# Opengl/SDL2 Help on accessviolation error on nivida cards

Tags: c#, opengl

So my code is

```
GLCore.TriFromRect(rect1,ref cords);
GLCore.glVertexPointer(2,GlEnums.GL_FLOAT,0,cords);
GLCore.glDrawArrays(GlEnums.GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);
```

For drawing a rectangle.
Im complieing to an opengl version 2.0 this is the version i want to support.
My current code above works on anyother computer using a external intel,ati and onboard intel or ati graphic card.

How ever the glDrawArrays function gives me an access violation on nivida cards such as my friends titan and my 430 geforce from 2005.

Any idea whats up?

Thanks for your time.
SDL2 is set up to request a 2.0 GL Context
and nivida and intel cards return 2.1 and the ati returns 2.0

GLEnv Setup

```
//Enable Double Buffering. 1=True 0=False
SDL.SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL.SDL_GLattr.SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);
//Set the Major and Minor Requested version to 2.0
SDL.SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL.SDL_GLattr.SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,2);
SDL.SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL.SDL_GLattr.SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,0);
//Keep the GL Context;
GLContext=SDL.SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
if (GLContext==IntPtr.Zero){
    throw new Exception("Failed to create GL context:"+SDL.SDL_GetError());
}else{
    //Keep a copy of the window handle
    GLWindow=window;
    //Show the window.
    SDL.SDL_ShowWindow(window);
    //Load GL Functions
    Load_GlFunctions();
    //Set Clear Color [Currently White]
    glClearColor(1f,1f,1f,1f);
    //Flush the graphic buffer.
    Flush();
    //Present the buffer.
    Present();
    //Tell the FrontEnd we are ready.
    GLInit=true;
}
```

Edit Important parts of GLCore

```
internal delegate void Gl3i1p(int i1,int i2,int i3,IntPtr val);
internal delegate void Gl3i1fa(int i1,int i2,int i3,float[] val);
internal delegate void Gl3i(int i1,int i2,int i3);
internal delegate void Gl1i(int i1);
internal static float[255] cords = new float[255];

public static void Flush() {
    GLCore.glClear(GlEnums.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GlEnums.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

public static void Present() {
    SDL.SDL_GL_SwapWindow(GLCore.GLWindow);
}

internal static T LoadUnmanagedFunction<T>(IntPtr functionpointer){
    var val = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(functionpointer,typeof(T));
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val,typeof(T));
}

internal static Gl1i glEnableClientState;
internal static Gl3i1fa glVertexPointer;
internal static Gl3i1fa glTexCoordPointer;
internal static Gl3i glDrawArrays;

private static void Load_GlFunctions(){
    glEnableClientState = LoadUnmanagedFunction<Gl1i>(SDL.SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glEnableClientState"));
    glVertexPointer = LoadUnmanagedFunction<Gl3i1fa>(SDL.SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glVertexPointer"));
    glTexCoordPointer = LoadUnmanagedFunction<Gl3i1fa>(SDL.SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glTexCoordPointer"));
    glDrawArrays = LoadUnmanagedFunction<Gl3i>(SDL.SDL_GL_GetProcAddress("glDrawArrays"));
}

internal static void TranglesFromRect(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2,ref float[] fill){
    float tmp=0f;
    if (x1 > x2) {
        tmp = x2;
        x2  = x1;
        x1  = tmp;
    }
    if (y1 > y2) {
        tmp = y2;
        y2  = y1;
        y1  = tmp;
    }
    fill[0]  = x1;
    fill[1]  = y1;
    fill[2]  = x2;
    fill[3]  = y1;
    fill[4]  = x2;
    fill[5]  = y2;
    fill[6]  = x2;
    fill[7]  = y2;
    fill[8]  = x1;
    fill[9]  = y2;
    fill[10] = x1;
    fill[11] = y1;
}
```

Comment: Yes i have tried to keep the array alive. cords is a static float array of 255
glVertexPointer passes the array as a pointer using marshalas

Comment: Please, post the SDL2 commands used for setting an OGL environment.

Comment: @Ripi2 Added as an edit

Comment: You're asking SDL for a OGL 2.1 version, not 2.0

Comment: yes i did change that a while ago.
as some times i know sdl will pick one if it cant get it. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Ripi2 This was a never version of code so see if setting to 2.1 would make any diffrence. the same error on the same card regardless of 2.0 or 2.1 the log says i got a 2.1 in both cases

Comment: Why are you calling [`SDL_GL_SetAttribute()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute) *after* you've created a window?  Those only affect the *next* `SDL_CreateWindow()` call.

Comment: SDL2 does it in reverse.
i used this as a guide http://headerphile.com/sdl2/opengl-part-1-sdl-opengl-awesome/
@genpfault

Comment: What is `GLCore`? Some wrapper library? Something written by yourself?

Comment: @BDL Yes it is. would you like a pastebin of it?

Comment: No pastebin. Add at least the relevant functions to the question itself so we can see what really gets called under the hood. And please also add the definiton of `cords` (or at least what it contains). With what we have now it is impossible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BDL i added that under edit:

Comment: Are you even sure it is an access violation with the data and not just the function address not being loaded correctly?

Comment: the intptr from sdl.getproc should throw an exception @BDL

Comment: @Rabbid76 called from the init function. and never disabled.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes it is called after create context. (otherwise intel and ati card wouldnt work ether)

Comment: Do you pin managed arrays passed as pointers?

Comment: No i do not. i could do but i see it making little difference. as if that was the issue why does my intel and ati computers work. @Luca

Comment: First, you should, for getting program correctness. Other GL drivers could work depending on they memory management. Check my wiki: https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/wiki/GL-%5C-Common-mistakes#pointer-arguments

Comment: @Luca My array is never collected. GC.KeepAlive and it is static.
it is passed by marshal to a void*

Comment: GC.KeepAlive will prevent GC to move the array?

Comment: @Luca normally yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it at last.

on nivida the 2D system does not work on my cards. passing my triangles in 3D with a 0 for Z fixes my issue and changeing my glDrawArrays to use 3 instead of 
2

Thanks for those who have tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

`glDrawArrays()` exists since OpenGL 1.1. This version was supported by Windows, *without the need of getting a function pointer to it*. Just use it as any other common function of your preferred language.

In fact, trying to get a function pointer with "GetProcAddress()" method may return a null pointer, which leads to a crash as soon as it get called.

Being that said, some graphics drivers may expose a function pointer for each OGL 1.1 command. Thus, using GetProcAddress may return a valid pointer. That explains why your code works in some machines but not in others.

My advise is: **don't use function pointers for commands existing in OGL 1.1**

Comment: ill give this go when im back home. on my nivida tower

Comment: Nope that didnt work. Dllimport loads it with no issue, intel card works but it still crashes on nivida

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code where you get a pointer to `glDrawArrays`. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47253921/3871028) may help.

Comment: I find this answer to be a bit misleading. When you talk about `GetProcAddress`, you actually mean [`wglGetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetprocaddress). The standard windows [`GetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) function will actually be able to load the GL 1.0 and 1.1 function pointers which are exported from `opengl32.dll`.

Comment: Furthermore, my recommendation would be the opposite: use a function pointer for each and every GL function, and don't even link the OpenGL lib. Just load it on runtime. GL loaders like GLAD will deal with the dirty details of needing two different `GetProcAddress` functions in certain situations. However, this is only my opinion and as such off-topic on stack overflow.